# "Too much recursion" error when trying to remove element from a div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a contenteditable div which may be dynamically modified with an ajax call, depending on user actions. The modification will consist of adding a 'span' element to the div. There is a possibility that elements with the same value of a custom attribute will be added, and I would like to implement some jquery to remove those elements as soon as they're added. Here is the code so far:

```
function remove_duplicate_elements() {
    $('#contenteditable_div').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
        var $seen = {};
        $('#contenteditable_div span').each(function() {
            $attr_val = $(this).attr('custom_tag');
            if ($seen[$attr_val]) {
                $(this).remove();
            } else {
                $seen[$attr_val] = true;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This works, but it causes jquery errors along the lines of "too much recursion", followed by "Node not found". Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: you do realize that doing `$(this).attr('custom_tag');` here actually requires your `span` element to have an attribute called `custom_tag`, something like this: `<span custom_tag>...</span>`...

Comment: if you don't have and css for (custom_tag) then empty them. it will do the same job ($("custom_tag").empty();)

Comment: @webeno - yes, I abstracted the name of the custom attribute for the purpose of this example.

Comment: @Tasos - Thanks for the suggestion. I do have CSS for those elements, and emptying leaves an artifact due to that. Also, it produces the same recursion error as remove().

Comment: Actually, this doesn't happen in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/vvptcrdv/

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Just needed to break the loop with 'return false' in the first condition:

```
...
if ($seen[$attr_val]) {
  $(this).remove();
  return false;
} else {
...
```

Comment: This occurs because when you call `remove` the `DOMModified` event occurs again. This happens  recursively until all duplicates are removed. It is sort of hackish in my opinion.

Comment: @soktinpk - Overlooked that. Thank you! If it's hackish, can you suggest a more reasonable alternative?